# 'pipe' function in Javascript not populating from CSV as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, parsing

I had this code working earlier, but made some changes and I'm not sure what I did to break it. The path to the .csv file is correct, and the code seems correct, but the array `raw_data` is empty after the function call.

```
require('./trip.js');
const parser = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
let raw_data = [];

function readFile() {
    fs.createReadStream('./trips.csv')
        .pipe(parser())
        .on('data', (data) => raw_data.push(data))
        .on('end', () => console.log('CSV has been piped into an array'));
}

const trips = async () => {
   await readFile();
   console.log(raw_data.length)
};
```

I expect the raw_data array to contain 9999 items. It contains zero. I am also not getting the console.log statement to execute on 'end'.

Comment: You can only await promises.

Answer (score 1):

readFile must return Promise   like this

```
require('./trip.js');
const parser = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
let raw_data = [];

function readFile() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      fs.createReadStream('./trips.csv')
        .pipe(parser())
        .on('data', (data) => raw_data.push(data))
        .on('end', resolve)
    );
}

const trips = async () => {
   await readFile();
   console.log(raw_data.length)
};
```